# Why is there a NoMethodError for end_game?

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I have a code like this:

```rb
    class Game
        ....
        def end_game?
           return win? || draw?
        end
        until end_game? do
           ....
        end
    end
```

I get this error:
`` undefined method `end_game?' for Game:Class (NoMethodError) `` at line 89 (that contains the until loop)

Comment: end_game is an instance method. You may want to define it as self.end_game? which would make it available to be called as you have there. your other method calls will have to be adjusted as well.

Comment: Move that loop _outside_ your class, e.g. `game = Game.new` followed by `until game.end_game? … end`

Comment: @prieber the problem with defining it as `self.end_game?` is that the concept (Class) of `Game` cannot end. Whether a `Game` is a win or a draw is based on the individual instance of `Game`. I cannot hand you a tic-tac-toe board and ask you the result of the `Game`. We can only find out by playing.

Comment: Oh I agree that there are problems with the design, but it’s something to try if they don’t want to refactor a bunch of thingsz